# How can I extract images from a video?

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, video, video-editor

How can I generate images from a video like screenshots? What are all the available options including command line and GUI approaches?

Comment: You asked the exact same question here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/185877, and here: http://superuser.com/questions/135117/how-to-convert-video-to-images is a nice set of answers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has been posted on multiple SE sites.

Comment: so, in another time I should only post on one site?

Answer (score 11):

You can do that with `ffmpeg` or [`avconv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/avconv.1).

To extract a single image:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -ss 00:00:14.435 -f image2 -vframes 1 out.png
avconv -i input.flv -ss 00:00:14.435 -f image2 -vframes 1 out.png
```

This will extract one frame (`-vframes 1`) from the position 0h:0m:14sec:435msec into the movie.

These pages may help:

- [How to take multiple screenshots to an image (tile, mosaic)](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20take%20multiple%20screenshots%20to%20an%20image%20%28tile,%20mosaic%29)
- [Create a thumbnail image every X seconds of the video](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video)

Source: [Create a thumbnail image every X seconds of the video](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video)

Answer (score 5):

You can install vlc and go to **File > Create snapshot**. It will create a snapshot of the current image in VLC.